# Google Maps Api cannot call function inside dragend event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Using react with the Google Maps Api and I am doing a nearbySearch to find and place pins for basketball courts. When the map is first loaded it works and places pins:

```
loadMap() {
    if (this.props && this.props.google) {
      // checks if google is available
      const { google } = this.props;
      const maps = google.maps;

      const mapRef = this.refs.map;

      // reference to the actual DOM element
      const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(mapRef);

      let { zoom } = this.props;
      const { lat, lng } = this.state.currentLocation;
      const center = new maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      const mapConfig = Object.assign(
        {},
        {
          center: center,
          zoom: zoom,
          options: options
        }
      );

      // maps.Map() is constructor that instantiates the map
      this.map = new maps.Map(node, mapConfig);

      // This is the function to display all the markers  
    
      this.searchCourts(); // This works properly

       // This one below fails

      this.props.google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, "dragend", function() {
           this.newSearchonDrag() //Error: this.NewSearchonDrag is not a function ????
      })
      }
    }
```

Here is the searchCourts function:

```
searchCourts = () => {
      const map = this.props.google.maps.Map

      const { google } = this.props;
      const maps = google.maps;

      const request = {
        location: this.map.getCenter(),
        radius: '50000',
        name: ['basketball court']
      }

      const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);

  // ACTUAL SEARCH FOR COURTS
      service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);  
          }
        }
      });

      // MARKERS TO BE DROPPED
     
    const createMarker= (place) => {
      let marker = new this.props.google.maps.Marker({
        map: this.map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        title: place.name
      });

      let infowindow = new this.props.google.maps.InfoWindow({
        name: place.name,
        vicinity: place.vicinity
      });  

      marker.addListener("click", function() {

        let contentString = `<div id="infowindow">` + place.name + `<br>` + place.vicinity + `</div> `
      
        infowindow.setContent(contentString)
        infowindow.open(this.map, marker)          
      })       
      }
    }
```

This works when the map loads and my newSearchonDrag() is essentially the same as searchCourts(), however I am able to find the newCenter of the map when it is dragged.

The issue it seems to me to be a scope issue...inside my dragend event..i cannot call any functions in my Map class...it seems the searchCourts() could be called each time the drag happens but I am not sure how to call it inside the event.

Comment: So i have function that is a SearchBar, and I placed a 'this.searchCourts()' in it and it worked..so to me it does seem to a scope issue..how do i call a class function within an event....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a bit of a hack to solve this issue. I created a function called FindCourts that renders a button, when the button is clicked it fires the searchCourts() function. So then within the map dragend event, i assigned a variable to the button and perform a button.click()...it works and I hid the button afterwards.

```
//Click Event
   maps.event.addListener(this.map, "dragend", function() {
              var button = document.querySelector("#root > div > header > div.NavBar > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div > button.findcourts")
              button.click()
            })

// And the button function

FindCourts = () => {     
      return (
        <button 
          className="findcourts"
          onClick={() => {
            this.searchCourts()
          }}
        >Find Courts
        </button>
      );
    }
```